# Sentence embeddings for extremely short texts (1-3 words/sentence)

Tags: embedding, fasttext

I have some texts which are extremely short which comes from banktransactions (80% of the dataset has less than 3 words), and I want to classify them into ~90.000 classes (supplier).
Since the text comes from bank-transactions a lot of words are not exact but often truncated, missspelled etc, thus BoW is not optimal since we have words as `facebk`, `facebook`, `faceboo` which are treated as different words.
FastText is a good candidate for creating embeddings, and word for word it creates some very good similarities.

The issue is when I want to create a sentence embedding. Since banktransactions often have (a lot) of "stop-words" eg. `facebook/zg181239 202392` or `MC 102930` it is extremly difficult to remove all "rubbish" words.

Using the mean of all the words as a sentence embedding does not work very well, since some transactions contain rubbish words, and since the sentences are so short those "noise" words have a big influence e.g `faceboo 1230jaisd` and `facebook 1231jaikj` are not very similar in the "sentence" space.

Is there a way to make some kind of sentence embedding that could handle this?

Answer (score 2):

With 90,000 classes and lots of thin/junk data, there may not be enough of a pattern there to learn a good classifier. (Do the classes at least have many diverse examples each?)

Still, some ideas:

1. If certain tokens or even token-fragments are reliable indicators that items must/must-not be from certain suppliers, a classifier based on the more-discrete features of a bag-of-words, or bag-of-character-n-grams, representation might do better. (Or, those features might help in places where the continuous word-vectors, alone or when combined into even fuzzier sums/means, have the greatest problems. That is, even your example of typos like `facebk` and `faceboo` still include the 4-character n-gram `face`, and the binary presence/absence of that fragment, in a sparse BoW/Bag-of-ngrams representation, may be a clearer signal to a downstream classifier than the continuous FastText n-gram vectors that'd be learned for `face`, after they've been mixed into the OOV vector synthesis than the multitoken average.)
2. If you suspect it's the particular 'noise' words causing problems – only very rarely helping a little, you could try things like:

   a. discarding all tokens below a certain frequency, that threshold TBD via experimentation;

   b. down-weight vectors for tokens that are below a certain frequency, or that have been OOV-synthesized via FastText's ngrams approach, compared to the vectors for more-common tokens, when averaging those together.

   c. represent each item as concatenation of the average of the frequent/known tokens, and a separate average of the sketchy/lower-frequency/OOV-synthesized tokens - so that those tokens you see as junk/noise don't necessarily dilute the better tokens, but are still contributing for the tougher cases. (You might also try feature-subsegments based on all-alpha or all-numeric or other subsets of the tokens.)
3. Both FastText itself & any downsream classifiers may have parameter-tuning options that could help, especially given that your data isn't true natural-language, and thus will have token/subword frequencies/patterns quite different from usual situations. (As one example: lots of arbitrary numbers are highly unlikely to have the same sort of vaguely-meaningful substrings as natural language, so maybe far higher or lower values of the `buckets` value would work better, or keeping most numeric info out of the word-vector modeling entirely.)

Comment: The 90.000 classes can be divided into smaller groups e.g a classifier for each user, and since each user has around 4-10 suppliers this helps.

The issue is more regarding how to represent each sentence. Using n-gram might be a better approach than BoW

Comment: But also: you may benefit from all the features - full-token BoW, character n-grams, and 1 or more dense-embeddings – to give your classifiers the best chance.